# Why we always get different accuracy for a different number of training our model?

Tags: neural-networks, accuracy

As the question says for example if I train my neural network (with 2 layers) model the first time it gives me a score $A \in \mathbb{R}$ and when I train the same model again it gives a **different** score $B \in \mathbb{B}$.

This is very strange for me and still cannot understand the reason why!

Comment: Does your network have a random component? For example, do you initialize the weights randomly, use dropout, shuffle the training data or have another random component to the model?

Comment: Thanks, @Sycorax. I am initializing my weights using `tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()` and my bais terms using `tf.zeros_initializer`.

Comment: @Sycorax How can I fix the random seed mentioned in https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/256599/224266 using TensorFlow, please?

Comment: I've added an additional duplicate target.

Comment: you set the seed in tensorflow using [set_random_seed](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/set_random_seed)